# SSRS 2008r2: rsRunTimeErrorInExpression: cannot find textbox stated in warning

Tags: reporting-services

I am using Sql Server Reporting Services 2008 R2. When "previewing" my current report, I see everything appearing as it should. The displayed query values are correct in my table, which reads straight from the single dataset.

However, I see this as a warning:

> Warning   1   [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox20.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.    E:\SSRS_Projects\Custom Reports\Attendance\Attendance\MIA_1B_Math_Absence_Detail.rdl    0   0

The puzzling thing is that I have no objects named "Textbox20."

- I tried browsing thorough the object list on the "Properties" panel
  and didn't see it.
- I did a Ctrl+F search for "Textbox20" and couldn't find anything.

I'm not sure what else I can describe at this point.

Does anyone know how I can isolate the cause of this warning?

Thank you

Comment: Do you encounter any problems running the report or it just a warning?

Comment: No "problems" in regard to viewing the report. I only see it as a warning in the "Error List" box. While "only" a warning, I try to address them in case it's pointing at a more important issue.

Comment: This might have been a phantom.  I pressed the green Debug button in the toolbar and viewed the report. This time, no warnings.  It's a very puzzling outcome, as I saw this warning all afternoon -- now it's gone, where I had done nothing different than I did before.

Comment: Not quite sure what the problem could had been, but glad it's been resolved. Worst case scenario you could had manually removed each text box until the warning went away. It's not the most straightforward approach but it could had been a final option.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the warning message was caused by the incorrect previous expression, however, the warning message persists although the values displays correctly in the report after you modified the expression. Besides, the warning message came out even though you create a new report and use the right expression.This is a known issue in Report Designer. When there is a warning message generated in the "Error List" pane of the Report Designer, the warning message still pops up after we correct the previous error. Actually, it always pops up whenever we preview any report in the same project. To avoid the issue, we only need to close the project and reopen the project. That way, the previous error lists will be cleared and the warning message won't pop out unless there is still an error in the report design.And your table's columns and rows are here text box.so please select the table column and see the property name.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this code

```
=IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!Data.Value),CSTR(FormatNumber(IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!Data.Value),Fields!Data.Value,0),2)),Fields!Data.Value)
```